# difference between spring webflow and MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

what is the basic difference between these two pattern how webflow runs on top of MVC I am not clear on these design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring MVC is a framework build on top of the model-view-controller pattern where you could bind a view(View layer) to a controller to display the data(Model).

Spring webflow inherits all of spring MVC features but is designed more as a state machine.

Webflow offers support for wizard style usecases when the output of an action is the input of another(transitions which can be bound to spring-beans).

For example :

> There is a clear start and an end point.
>
> The user must go through a set of screens in a specific order.
>
> The changes are not finalized until the last step.
>
> Once complete it shouldn't be possible to repeat a transaction accidentally

You can find more info on this topic [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/web-flow/7159-difference-between-spring-mvc-web-framework-and-web-flow)